# Best way to implement view like map

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, swift, drawrect

I'm making view that represent something like map, with pan and pinch gestures.
At current moment it's implemented via overriden drawRect that called in handlePan with setNeedsDisplay.
So, the resulting performance a little bit awkward. Is there any more appropriate approaches?

Comment: Have you had a look at the CATiledLayer class? It sound like this would solve your issue, but may be a bit more complicated. Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/index.html . There are a lot of tutorials on how to use it properly, just use a search engine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, more appropriate solution here is UIScrollView.

To get it work:

1. Set up scrollView delegate, like

> scrollView.delegate = self

2. Implement

> func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
>
> ```
> {
>     return fieldView
> }
> ```

Optionally, you can set

> scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scrollView.frame.width /
>   fieldView.frame.width
>           scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2

Where fieldView is target custom view:

> fieldView = FieldView(frame: frameRect)
>
> scrollView.addSubview(fieldView)
>
> scrollView.contentSize = frameRect.size